# What to do if your manager said you're being inconsiderate because you had to go home sick?

Tags: professionalism, sickness

I work in a care home. I came to work and was feeling very OK, but a few hours passed and I became sick, had severe stomach issues, felt dizzy and was not even able to hold a pen. I went to my manager and told her I was sick & had to go home. However, my senior was not around for me to inform her, and my manager said that it wasn't in her ability to let me go. I would have to wait for my senior to come back. After an hour of waiting, she returned.

I went to her and told her everything, to which she said she had to speak to the manager. She came to me later and said if the sickness was that bad, I should go home, but that I should go to my manager and speak to her. I went to my manager again, but she said that I shouldn't leave and am being inconsiderate. She said I should wait, that there are just 3 hours left to finish, but that it was up to me if I want to leave or not. I had to leave out of anger and on the way going home I actually had an accident in my pants because of how severe my sickness was... How do I handle a situation like this?

Comment: You may as well give us your country tag.

Comment: *"How do I handle a situation like this?"* - well... perhaps you are still not feeling completely ok, but the question here is what do *you* want to do? What is your goal? Sounds like a very unreasonable manager/supervisor TBH... please enhance what do you want to do (your goal) so we can help you with it... hope you feel better soon

Comment: You work in a care home, you tell them you're sick, and they don't even care... shouldn't health issues be a no. 1 priority for a care home? What if you are infected with something communicable?

Comment: "_How do I handle a situation like this?_" You already handled it. You stayed. You should not. Your own health is the most important thing in the world. You were lucky this time. Good luck may not be with you every time. The one who is inconsiderate is your manager, not you.

Answer (score 2):

A first step is to look at the company's written policy around sickness and how to notify your supervisors of the need for an unplanned sick day or leaving a shift early due to severe illness.  This is something that should be in an employee handbook somewhere.

Sounds like the series of event were

- notify manager - get told to tell supervisor
- supervisor unavailable for 1 hour
- supervisor requires you to stay until they can talk to manager
- (wait period?)
- get told you can leave but really you should talk to manager first
- go to manager, get encouraged to stay and get negative feedback
- leave, there was some negative feedback, but not a tangible penalty (like getting suspended, formally reprimanded, etc).

**Case 1:  Everyone followed the rules**

If it was really true that this series of events was legitimate and you're supposed to effectively have TWO different people sign off on you leaving under urgent illness conditions... maybe it's time to propose a change to the rules?  It's a reasonable conversation to talk about how long you should have to wait before leaving.  Can the rules get updated?  For example - if the supervisor is unavailable for more than 20 minutes, can the manager take charge?

**Case 2:  The process you went through was nothing like the rules**

Bring it up - point out that you shouldn't have had to wait around for literally hours to the extend that you then had problems getting home safely and w/out incident.  Ask your supervisors to own following the process properly and if they won't, escalate to Human Resources or whoever else is responsible for making sure the process is followed.

**Some mitigating factors**

- the nature of your job and the number of other people on the shift who could do what you do is a big deciding factor in terms of what's reasonable.  If you are the only person with the skills to prevent certain very bad outcomes (like the people you care for being seriously hurt or dying), then it may very well be inconsiderate, no matter how ill you are.  OTOH - if you are part of a reasonable staffing plan, it should be possible for a single member of a functional team to go home sick.
- what's "inconsiderate" has a lot to do with frequency of sickness, how it was communicated (including body language), personal biases and a lot of other factors - it's really hard for anyone in a forum like this to judge accurately why this was said by your superiors, or why.  It's worth probing with them why they describe your behavior this way, and what part of it specifically is inconsiderate.
- the pattern of the team around you.  If your bosses have had to deal with staffing shortages, and unexpected absences across your shift, or multiple shifts, they may be at their wits end, and those comments may not have been particular to you.  It may also be worth a probe there to see why they can't handle 1 person being out sick and what it does to the rest of the staff.  Not to say that this will fix much, but it might give you a clue what's up here.